# bash Command line substitution in for loop

Tags: bash, loops, command-line

I have a test script test.sh where  I am trying to print out command line arguments.to the script but the following does not work as expected

```
`#!/bin/bash
 for((i=1;i<"$#";i++)) do
        printf "Position %s of argumentArray has  %s \n", $i  $(($i))
  done`
```

( my idea was that the (()) will do the mathematical evaluation resulting in $1 $2 etc.) Neither does

```
for((i=1;i<"$#";i++)) do
printf "Position %s of argumentArray has  %s \n", $i  $"$( eval echo $i )"
done
```

both gives as out put when run as follows

```
./test.sh  first second third 

Position 1 of argumentArray has  1 
Position 1 of argumentArray has  2
Position 1 of argumentArray has  3
```

instead of

```
Position 1 of argumentArray has  first 
Position 1 of argumentArray has  second
Position 1 of argumentArray has  third
```

I face the same problem with

```
for((i=1;i<="$#";i++)) 
  do
      case "$($i)" in
       .......
```

case evaluates to 1 ,2 3 etc insted of the actual parameter passed in.

Please help me in understanding where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commandline arguments can be accessed directly but *if you want them by position* you can do this:

```
arguments=($@)
for ((i = 0; i < ${#arguments[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "arguments[$i] = ${arguments[$i]}"
done
```

A run of the script:

```
$ ./args.sh first second third
arguments[0] = first
arguments[1] = second
arguments[2] = third
```

**ADDENDUM**

Information on Bash arrays:

- [Array chapter from the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)
- [15 Array tutorials](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks it works. Forgot about arays altogether

I went on to do.
`
    for((i=1;i<"$#";i++)) do
    str=$(  echo $( eval echo \$$( echo  $i )))
    echo $str
    printf "Position %s of batchProcessArray has  %s \n", $i  "$str"
    done
`
but your answer is the best solution. thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [indirect expansion](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to do this fairly easily:

```
for((i=1;i<=$#;i++)) do
    printf "Position %s of argumentArray has  %s \n" $i  "${!i}"
done
```

I also fixed some minor problems in the above: the loop end condition should be `i<=$#` to print the last arg, there shouldn't be a comma after the format string for `printf`, and there should be double-quotes around the argument (`"${!i}"`) in case it has any spaces or other funny characters.